# Setting state within a React method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that passes a value (e) into a filter, e will always be one of these values: {true, false, SHOW_ALL}.

```
filterItem(e) {  
    this.state.filter[0].Status = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
         filter: this.state.filter
    });
 }
```

React is complaining that I am modifying state directly.  Getting this warning:  **Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()**

I can't figure out how to set the filter status to the e.target.value, AND include in the assign inside setState();  To set the status I have to assign e.target.value to the Status property like so:

```
 this.state.filter[0].Status = e.target.value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filterItem(e) {
    this.setState({
        filter: e.target.value
    });
}
```

`this.state.filter[0].Status = e.target.value;` is mutating the state directly. You are directly assigning a value to the state, rather than using the provided `setState()` function. This violates one of React's 3 key principles, as stated in the warning you got.

Another thing to note: Status is a reserved word, so you shouldn't use it as a property name.

Also, `this.state.filter[0].Status` implies that `this.state.filter` is an array, and you are changing the property `Status` of its first element. Unless `this.state.filter` needs to hold multiple elements/items, each with their own `Status` property, you can just keep it as `this.state.filter`.

If that was intentional, then you can change the function to this:

```
filterItem(e) {
    this.setState({
        filter: [{Status: e.target.value}]
    });
}
```

Comment: It's good that you mention it, but I don't think the use of `Status` here is bad. Partly because it is capitalized (the reserved word is all lower-case) and partly because it is a key to an object and not a variable

Comment: Thank you!  I see now.  You make some very salient points about how I am implementing things.  I am actually refactoring a bunch of code from different sources into what I am trying to write. Works great!

Comment: You both make some good points though.  It's basically just a status property for Todo's.  The Array part for the filter[x] was me using some key/value pairs here... [0] being for todo status, and [1] for search term, but I think I am going to split these into separate components.  The use of an array here isn't necessary.  Thanks for that.

Comment: `status` is not a reserved word, but it should be in camelCase to follow conventions

Comment: @chris which reserved word? Am I missing something?

Comment: @JonasW. getting a bit too technical perhaps, but apparently `status` is the same as `window.status` (when used in the console). This may cause syntax highlighting in some environments. Again though, I don't think using it is bad here.

Comment: @chris and thats not a keyword.

Comment: @JonasW. true, it isn't. But type `status` in your console and you get an emtpy string instead of a reference error.

Comment: @Rachel please pick a best answer if one of us have effectively answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a copy of your existing array

`const filter = [...this.state.filter]`

then you can mutate this copy

`filter[0].Status = e.target.value;`

and then you can use setState

`this.setState({filter: filter})`

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this one too and works.  Thank you for taking the time to suggest!

Comment: @JonasW. Yes, that's true, I forgot about it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning it directly like so:

```
this.state.filter[0].Status = e.target.value;
```

You can do something like this.

```
this.setState({filter: [{status: e.target.value}] })
```

Comment: Thank you.  This one is like the first responder.  Thank you for taking the time to suggest

Comment: @Rachel, if my answer solves your issue, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually a bit complicated:

```
this.setState(previous => ({
     filter: [{
        ...previous.filter[0],
        Status: e.target.value
     }].concat(previous.filter.slice(1))
}));
```

*PS: This is one of the cases were i would prefer simplicity over strict state transitions, so just ignore the warning ;)*

Comment: This is interesting as well, and a different way of looking at the issue. Everything is sans Redux here.  Thank you!